# How can I combine my 2 codes to work in such a way that part 1 of the code opens and starts part 2? (Konami code into obstacle course game)

Tags: javascript

I'm a student trying to learn Javascript. So a while ago I made a Konami code inspired thingy that plays audio when you type something. Later on I made an obstacle course game by following a tutorial. There were some hiccups on the way, but I made them work with slight adjustments here and there. I try to avoid ChatGPT as much as I can, because I want to learn as much as I can. I mostly use it to add comments, explain bits of code, or help adjust/shorten what I already made.

What I want to do now is to combine the two. I want the game to show up and start (and possibly have a start/restart button) after the code has been typed on the webpage. Not sure if showing the HTML/CSS is needed here (didn't want to clutter the post too much). But if you do need it, let me know. I marked the two codes with "FIRST HALF" and "SECOND HALF".

My question is: How can I do this in a simple (or at least a not too complicated) way?

```
// FIRST HALF
const pressed = [];
const secretCode = 'enorm';
var audio = new Audio('nobullshit.mp3');

// Event listener for keyup events on the window
window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    pressed.push(e.key);
    // Trim the array to match the length of the secret code
    pressed.splice(0, pressed.length - secretCode.length);

    const word = pressed.join('');
    console.log(pressed);
    const game = document.getElementById('achtergrond');

    // Check if the typed word matches the secret code and adjust the game visibility
    if (word === secretCode) {
        game.style.visibility = 'visible'
    } else {
        game.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    }

    // If the typed word matches the secret code, log a message and play an audio file
    if (word === secretCode) {
        console.log('DIT IS ENORM!');
        audio.play();
    } 
});

// SECOND HALF
// Get references to DOM elements
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var obstacle = document.getElementById("obstacle");
var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");

// Initialize variables
var score = 0;
var obstacleScored = false;

// Function to animate the player character
function spring() {
    if (character.classList != "animate") {
        character.classList.add("animate");
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        character.classList.remove("animate");
    }, 500);
}

// Collision checking interval
var checkDead = setInterval(function () {
    // Get the current positions of the character and obstacle
    var characterTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
    var obstacleLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obstacle).getPropertyValue("left"));

    // Check if the character collided with the obstacle
    if (obstacleLeft < 30 && obstacleLeft >= 0 && characterTop >= 130) {
        // Game over scenario
        obstacle.style.animation = "none";
        obstacle.style.display = "none";
        resultDiv.textContent = "Je bent geraakt! Score: " + score;
    } else if (obstacleLeft <= 5 && !obstacleScored) {
        // The obstacle has passed the character successfully
        score++;
        obstacleScored = true; // Set the flag to true to prevent scoring the same obstacle multiple times
    }

    // Reset the obstacleScored flag when the obstacle is off the screen
    if (obstacleLeft < -10) {
        obstacleScored = false;
    }
}, 30);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

These codes work individually, which is good. But what I want is for the code that's needed for the audio to also start the second half of the code, which is an obstacle game. I tried a few things last week and don't really remember it much. One thing I do remember is that I've tried putting the obstacle course game in "if (word === secretCode) { }", but that didn't really work (as expected to be honest).

Comment: I have to admit your question is a little bit broad. Also you ask for 'simple approach' but this is opinion based. I would advise you to use classes and learn OOP which is easier to maintain and combine IMO. But this could be more complex to learn.. Also side note: Don't mix up dutch and english names!

Comment: I'll try to keep things in English next time to make it cleaner and easier to keep track of. I'm still learning basics. I can read and understand codes fine for the most part (basic stuff), but properly building stuff myself is still an issue for some reason. Is there something you'd recommend like a YouTube course or free online course (up until a certain point)?

Comment: Well this is also very opionbased but you could consider watching Code Train: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTWrWM1UsnA. He uses p5.js, which is a library that will help you a lot if you want to focus on making games with JS :) He uses OOP principles in every project and explains it very clean! I hope this helps! Another side note: Consider making a JS fiddle or somethings else so we can see it working/breaking

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look. Also, I'm not specifically working towards making games. I just happen to be working on a project that involves making a simple game haha. I'll try to work with fiddle as well in the future.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.